# Typescript code generator for Python, Kotlin & Dart

Tags: typescript, kotlin, compiler-construction, code-generation, dsl

I want to make a domain specific language. The "source code" is yml. Compilation targets should be TypeScript, Kotlin, Python and Dart.

I already wrote a parser in TypeScript which outputs my abstract syntax tree as JSON.

Can I efficiently generate source code for Python, Kotlin & Dart from TypeScript? Or should I use Python/Kotlin to generate the three other languages?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If by "generate source code in X", you mean "generate a text file which is a valid X program" —and I can't think of what else you might mean— then there is absolutely no advantage to writing the generator in the same language as you're generating. Text is text. Use the language you are most comfortable with.

Comment: You can write a compiler in just about any language. It just depends on your context, e.g., how you want to run it and distribute it.